# "The incoming event is not a valid request from Amazon API Gateway or an Application Load Balancer" lambda Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, postman, policy

I am trying to do the most basic Proof of Concept api but every time I call my lambda function URL from Postman, I get

```
com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.InvalidRequestEventException: 
    The incoming event is not a valid request from Amazon API Gateway or an Application Load Balancer
```

I have the Auth type: NONE, CORS: "*", Allow methods: "*"

Policy:

```
{
      "Sid": "FunctionURLAllowPublicAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunctionUrl",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:11111:function:my-api",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "lambda:FunctionUrlAuthType": "NONE"
        }
      }
    }
```

I found [this issue](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/issues/245#:%7E:text=the%20framework%20expects%20an%20event%20that%20is%20shaped%20like%20an%20API%20Gateway%20or%20ALB%20proxy%20event.) which says that "the framework expects an event that is shaped like an API Gateway or ALB proxy event." and links to [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format) However, how would I do this in Postman?

[This AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html#:%7E:text=If%20your%20function%20URL%20uses%20the%20NONE%20auth%20type%2C%20you%20don%27t%20have%20to%20sign%20your%20requests%20using%20SigV4.%20You%20can%20invoke%20your%20function%20using%20a%20web%20browser%2C%20curl%2C%20Postman%2C%20or%20any%20HTTP%20client.) suggests that I don't need to do that though:

> If your function URL uses the NONE auth type, you don't have to sign your requests using SigV4. You can invoke your function using a web browser, curl, Postman, or any HTTP client.

However, perhaps the problem is the conversion of the request into the Amazon API Gateway payload schema? From the same document:

> When a client calls your function URL, Lambda maps the request to an event object before passing it to your function. Your function's response is then mapped to an HTTP response that Lambda sends back to the client through the function URL.

> The request and response event formats follow the same schema as the Amazon API Gateway payload format version 2.0.

Anyone know what I need to change to be able to call a simple GET request from a browser/Postman?

Comment: What HTTP status do you get back from postman? Also the error you get back, do you see it in your lambda logs or in the postman response? Either way one of them is missing for us to understand the problem a bit more. Would also be good to know more about your lambda and api gateway setup, as it's probably not only about the policy

Comment: Hello Have you fixed it? I've been struggling to test simple GET spring boot function via Lambda function. Lambda function is not straightforward thing. Please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76577207/spring-boot-deployed-in-lambda-throws-statuscode-502-gateway-timeout?noredirect=1#comment135029745_76577207

Answer (score 0):

If you are directly invoking an AWS Lamda function there are a number of conventions you need to conform to (content type being applicatin/json, the [body configured per request structure in the invocation doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html)  ).

This is because the lambda is effectively a generic function that can be invoked and there are conventions to how information and parameters are passed.

However it would be more typical to configure an api gateway service to invoke your lambda. Full [documentation on configuring api gw to lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html) is long, but there is a [quickstart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html). Note: many people who are wanting to manage this configuration as code will set up a configuration system above all of these concepts such as "serverless.com" that configures the lambda and the api gw via cloudformation where inputs are controlled [via a .yaml file in your code base](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api).

The API gateway configuration (either manually or through a system like serverless.com) effectively just maps the usual structure of an http call (GET vs POST, query string, path, etc.) into the generalized function calling structure in the json body that lambda invocation expects . Again the reason the mapping or nesting exists is that there are other structures of call that trigger lambdas (e.g. changes in a dynamodb, async queues, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, but your first link is that same as the one I posted which explicitly says: "To test simple GET requests to your function, use a web browser. For Example: ... https://abcdefg.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/?message=HelloWorld" I understand that if this does become a real app that I will need a gateway, but I'm not trying to do that right now

Comment: Ahh cool, I hadn't used the direct function urls before, it appears they are an addition in the last year: https://towardsdatascience.com/aws-lambda-function-urls-2d87d88961fc I have typically only used the original api gateway pattern.  Looking further, and confirming you did these console steps to enable: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-configuration.html#create-url-console  (I realize you confirmed setting auth type none and cors but wanted to understand if it was set through that configuration)

Comment: Yes, it was set when I created the function and then double checked after. I spoke with one of the devops guys and he said he has been struggling with it too. Maybe AWS is just struggling with roll out?

Comment: Perhaps; I know it is not your core question, but I would add that using API GW was not difficult in the past so that may be a faster path for you.

Comment: Hello Have you fixed it? I've been struggling to test simple GET spring boot function via Lambda function. Lambda function is not straightforward thing. Please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76577207/spring-boot-deployed-in-lambda-throws-statuscode-502-gateway-timeout?noredirect=1#comment135029745_76577207